# Best data type to store a choice 1, 2 or 3

Tags: java

I have a program which reads a type, say type of car, its asked to user to enter the type i.e 1, 2 or 3. I am looking for best data type to store this variable which only has the values 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: int or char, if it's that simple

Comment: `enum`, `byte` and `int` all have their upsides. You can ask what they are, but it's up to you to choose between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for an *enum type*:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: yeah thought of the same, but confirming as I am new to java,thanks

Comment: You know, if you've already thought of solutions, it's best to mention that in your question so we don't need to give you links to answers you already know.

Comment: hmm I know the enum data type, but wondered if java has anything more to offer , yeah u are right I should had mentioned that

Comment: @Snedden27 what limitation do you see with the enum where it doesn't satisfy what you are  looking for?  Asking if java has more to offer is a terrible vague and open question, and you likely won't get any helpful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Boolean type, and if you use a database, you must set it to allow null value in database.

This way you technically have these 3 values.

**TRUE**; **FALSE**; **NULL**

But this way the field must be **required**, otherwise it would keep information that is not inserted by the user.

Comment: `Boolean` or `boolean` ?

Comment: to achieve null you can't use boolean, it would have to be Boolean.  boolean is a primitive type and therefore can not be null in java.  Enums are still your best bet.